# Change 'P' tag text color within a div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I change the p tag text color css attribute using jQuery? I don't want to change all p tags, just a particular one....

Is this possible without adding an id for every p tag?

```
<div class = "custimage"><img src = "img/notch.jpg" alt = "notch"/><p>Notch</p></div>
<div class = "custimage"><img src = "img/peak.jpg" alt = "peak"/><p>Peak</p></div>
<div class = "custimage"><img src = "img/shawl.jpg" alt = "shawl"/><p>Shawl</p></div>
```

EDIT:

I want it so that when the user clicks on a particular custimage, the p tag text color is changed. I have tried:

```
$('.custimage').click(function(e) {
               var cssObj = {
                  'background-color' : '#fff'
               }
               $(this).css(cssObj);
               $('this p').css({color: '#000'});
});
```

This doesn't work. Using `$('.custimage p').css({color: '#000'});`changes the colour of the text in all the images...

Comment: Which one do you want to change, and what constants can be used to find it (i.e. the paragraph next to a certain image, the last one, the 3rd one, the one with the text "Shawl" etc.)?

Comment: It would be the one that the user has clicked on

Comment: OK yeah, that's pretty important - you should have included that in your original post - now you have 6 guess answers (3 deleted) because people jump all over the easy jquery questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to change the color of the p tag inside the clicked `.custimage` div like this:

```
$('.custimage').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('p').css({color: '#000'});
});
```

The `.find()` function traverses down the DOM tree to find any tag that matches the given selector. You can read more about the `.find()` function at http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

$(".custImage p") would get you all p tag's within a div with that class. You could then do what you want. If you give me more information I'll give you a better selector.

Comment: how could I get a particular custimages p tag...based on a user clicking on a particular custimage div

Answer (score 0):

To change a specific 'p' using text contents as a selector -

```
$("p:contains('Notch')").css("color","red");
```

to get the one inside the div with class `.custimage` that was clicked -

```
$('.custimage').click(function(e) {$(this).find('p').css("color","red")});
```

Comment: nice idea but for my purposes it's too specific

Comment: Added selector to get 'p' in clicked div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').each(function(index) {
    //Lets say you want to target P number 2
    if(index = "2")  {
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }
});
```

or you could target the image or alt tag.. would that work for you?